# Выполнить метод при закрытии активити

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Есть две активити "MainActivity" и "SecondActivity". Можно каким-нибудь образом выполнить метод в "MainActivity" при возврате с "SecondActivity" на "MainActivity", но чтобы он не выполнялся при создании "MainActivity", срабатывал лишь после закрытия "SecondActivity"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Да, можно. Для этого запускайте вторую активити через `startActivityForResult`, после её закрытия у первой активити будет вызван метод `onActivityResult`

Comment: Спасибо, решил помогло решение.